# How to delete a file on MacOS that gives error "No such file or directory"?

Tags: hard-drive

On an external FAT32 hard drive there is a file in the Bin (`.Trashes`) which I cannot delete. Even when I try to delete it on the command line using

```
rm offending_file
```

I get an error

```
rm: offending_file: No such file or directory
```

I also just ran the "First Aid" from the "Disk Utility" but that tool did not find any issues.

So what else can I do to remove/fix that file?

Also, when I try to remove the folder containing that file with

```
rm -rf folder
```

I get the error

```
rm: folder/: Permission denied
```

even when I run the command with `sudo` rights.

`ls -l` of the containing folder shows

```
-rwx------  1 alex  staff  67755741 Oct 18 04:51 offending_file
```

When opening the "Bin" on MacOS I only see an empty folder I cannot delete immediately as an error pops up saying the item "is in use", which, of course, is not the case.

Answer (score -4):

Solution: Plug in the disk in a computer with proper OS (e.g. `Windows`) and simply delete the file!

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer did in fact work!

Comment: Using a computer where FAT32 is a native disk format is actually a good idea, but implying that macOS isn't a proper OS won't help to make friends here.

Comment: @nohillside If an OS is not able to delete a single file, what will you call that?

Comment: Without proper analysis of the cause, that's hard to say. Maybe just restarting the drive fixed whatever issue you have been seeing first, or the FAT32 driver in macOS has a bug, or the FAT32 driver in Windows has a bug which makes it ignore the error, or ...

Comment: Of course I did restart everything. And this is not the only issue I have with MacOS. Also, I was VERY nice ...